# Principled Volume not working?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

Volume Scatter works fine but I used to work with principled volume to create fog, however I can't seem to make it work now after updating to blender 2.9, any suggestions?

Comment: Unplug what you have connected to the surface.

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative that you know: use "Volume Scatter" instead "Principled Volume".

I had the same issue - but someone already opened a ticket: https://developer.blender.org/T80332 - to solve it.